# flask.request.form.getlist returns empy list

Tags: jquery, forms, flask, post

Here is jQuery codes to generate hashtag as input field which are generated from another input field by pressing space key. Unfortunately can't catch values of tags after form post using flask form request method and the result is an empty list.

```
tags = flask.request.values.getlist('hashtag')
print(tags) >>>>>>> []




    const SPACE = 32
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === SPACE) {
            if ($('.tagContainer').length <= 9) {
                let tag = $('<div class="tagContainer">').append('<span class="material-icons-outlined closeTag">cancel</span>');
                $('<input>').attr({
                    'value': $('#tags').val(),
                    'name': 'hashtag',
                    'maxLength': 10,
                    'disabled': true,
                    'class': 'hashtags'
                }).appendTo(tag);
                $('.tagList').append(tag);
                $(this).val('');
                $('.tagContainer').on('click', function () {
                    $(this).remove()
                });
            }
        }
    });
});



<div class="tagContainer"><span class="material-icons-outlined closeTag">cancel</span><input value="asdasdasd" name="hashtag" maxlength="10" disabled="disabled" class="hashtags"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by removing 'disabled':true from jQuery commands, instead add CSS property: pointer-events: none;
And now flask can already catch the lists from disabled input field